# How to remove \/ slashes I want only / in Drupal8 JSON Output

Tags: drupal-8

```
[{"field_backgroundimage":"http:\/\/localhost\/drupal\/sites\/default\/files\/2016-10\/image1_3.jpg"}]
```

How to remove `\/` slashes, I want only `/`. I think it is coming in Raw JSON Format. How to Convert It into Pretty JSon Format. In Postman it is coming fine in Pretty format.

Answer (score 0):

can you not post-treat the json output ?

```
$string = str_replace("\/", "/", $string);
```